# Is it possible to use continuous delivery with JHipster?

Tags: jhipster, continuous-delivery

I am working on a JHipster project, and I would like to know if it is possible to use continuous delivery with JHipster or not?

Answer (score 1):

A JHipster app is just a Spring Boot app, so yes it is possible to use continuous delivery.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I wanted to use continuous delivery before continuous deployement: To deploy my application to Heroku, i used the command : "jhipster heroku " but still I am looking for a way to use continuous delivery.

Answer (score 1):

Continuous delivery is usually just a step at the end of your continuous integration job that says "deploy to XX". JHipster has great support for many CI/CD platforms with its [CI-CD subgenerator](https://www.jhipster.tech/setting-up-ci/).

```
jhipster ci-cd
```

From there, it's just a matter of configuring your CI server to deploy on success.

Comment: Thanks for your answer